# mysql configuration file order of read

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I was reading about `my.cnf` in mysql docs and I dont understand this part

> On Unix and Unix-like systems, MySQL programs read startup options from the files shown in the following table, in the specified order (files listed first are read first, files read later take precedence).

I am in doubt if the meaning of this text is that configuration in later files overwrite the same configuration in first files read

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking what is the order of operation for config files in MySQL using Unix as in the title? Or is the question, when you update the file does it overwrite the file?

Comment: Side note - Try using MySQL Workbench, its like Excel for MySQL, unless you  prefer to type everything by hand, and yep, even works in the free os such as you are using.

Comment: What else could it possibly mean?

Comment: "I am in doubt if the meaning of this text is that configuration in later files overwrite the same configuration in first files read". That's exactly what it means.

Comment: What do you think "files read later take precedence" means?

Answer (score 2):

> files read later take precedence

means that if you have the same option in multiple files, the setting in the last file that's read will be used.